# How to optimise RAM usage of sentiment analysis?

Tags: r, optimization, sentiment-analysis

So I scraped down 80000 comments from a subreddit (and 300000 from an other one) and I tried to get a sentiment value on it with the following line of code:

`sentiment <- analyzeSentiment(intelcommentdf$comment)`

the function is from the SentimentAnalysis R package. My issue is that I get this error message: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.2 Gb".
I only have 16gb or RAM.

I don't believe I need that much memory to analyse 20mb of comments, is there a more optimal way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but the [quanteda package does sentiment analysis](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/advanced-operations/targeted-dictionary-analysis/) well, and I'd be surprised if you'd run into memory issues. If you still do run out of memory, you can process your data in chunks your machine can handle (i.e. feed the comments in in batches of 1000 at a time, store results, process next batch).

Comment: @Till Thank you, I will try both of those methods!